# Angular2 TestBed Inject

Tags: angular, jasmine, testbed

I'm testing a service (`myService`) in Angular 2 that has a dependency on `Router`. Since I'm using one of Angular's components, I'm going to use Angular's `TestBed` class. So I set up my `beforeEach` as follows:

```
let router: Router;
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                {provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub}
            ]
        });
        router = TestBed.get(Router);
        myService = new MyService(router);
    }));
```

where `RouterStub` is defined as

```
@Injectable()
export class RouterStub {
    navigate() {};
}
```

Now I write my test to fail (red, green, refactor... )

```
it('on myServiceMethod calls router', () => {    
    let spy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');

    // myService.myServiceMethod(); // commented out so test fails

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

and the test fails as expected. However, I now try and write the same test using the `TestBed` `Inject` function, i.e.,

```
it('on myServiceMethod calls router', () => {
    inject([Router], (router: Router) => {
        let spy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');

       // myService.myServiceMethod(); // commented out so test fails

        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })   
})
```

and this test passes even though I thought the `Inject` function would retrieve the same instance of `Router` from the `TestBed`. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Have you tried with `RouterModule.forRoot()` in your `TestBed`?, Router service won't be injected if you don't call `forRoot()`. But it's just a long shoot.

Comment: @camaron Good thought, but unfortunately doesn't fix it. Seems odd this, and can only assume I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Mate it you should use `getTestBed` from `@angular/core/testing` and inject it like,

```
  getTestBed().get(YourService)
```

Comment: But isn't that what I'm doing in the first test that passes? Yes, this works and is what I'm currently using, but the question is more about understanding the `inject` function.